# Not all hammer.js events fire in ripple

Tags: javascript, hammer.js, ripple

'm trying to include some gestures in this phonegap project I am working on. I decided to go with hammer.js and I added the following code.

```
       function handleHammer(e) {
            console.log("SWIIIIPE" + e.type);
        }
        $('#categories_page').hammer({ drag_lock_to_axis: true })
            .on("tap", handleHammer);
```

This works great when I test on my local browser. But when I test it on ripple and on an actual phone the event is not fired.

I looked at some code samples and I found that if I change the events to

```
       $('#categories_page').hammer({ drag_lock_to_axis: true })
            .on("release dragleft dragright swipeleft swiperight", handleHammer);
```

I can see that events fire correctly on ripple.

Is there a problem with hammer.js or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score -1):

Actually I tried this again on the a real phone and it worked. Must have been doing something wrong. Still doesn't work on ripple. Annoying not only a minor issue.